# fluent ui styling, border is not defined

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, griffel.js

i am using fluent ui which uses Griffel for styling. When i try to provide border: "none" it's throwing error that string not assignable to undefined

```
import {makeStyles} from "@fluentui/react-components";
export const settingsButtonStyle = makeStyles({
    root: {
      border: "none",
      background: "#E5E5E5",
      marginRight: "13px"
    },
    rootHovered: {
      background: "#E5E5E5",
    }

});
```

[image]

Comment: let's see the error at top `ESLint: Error: Failed to load plugin...Cannot find module 'typescript'`. So let's trying install `npm i typescript -d`, then re-open vscode again

Answer (score 4):

GriffelJS tries to make Atomic CSS classes, so they don't support CSS shorthands (like border or background) right away. But there is a helper function called `shorthands` to manage some of theses. Background is not included in the helper function, so there you should use the specific CSS proprety. So your code should look like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        ...shorthands.border("0"),
        // or
        ...shorthands.borderStyle("none"),
        backgroundColor: "#E5E5E5",
        marginRight: "13px"
    },
})
```

You find more infos to shorthands in GriffelJS in their documentation [shorthands - GriffelJS](https://griffel.js.org/react/api/shorthands)

Comment: What if i want to do background: `linear-gradient(45deg, #0099b9 50%, #303f9f 100%)`? it doesn't work with shorthands

Comment: `backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #0099b9 50%, #303f9f 100%)'` should work in this case